# In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

```
select users.name,users.user_id,COUNT(subscribers.user_id) 
from users
LEFT JOIN subscribers 
  ON subscribers.to_id = users.user_id;
```

It gives the error `In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column users.name; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

I have two possible solutions

1. If i do `GROUP BY users.user_id,users.name` its fixed; but since i
   wrote my application in mysql < 5.7 i have to change lots of
   queries( its a nightmare).
2. I can turn off `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`.

   But i dont know if it is a bad practice ? does it has any pro cons of turning off`only_full_group_by`. ? performance wise which is better ?

Comment: MySql is not the same as Oracle, tag removed

Comment: Tough luck... I'd go with alternative 1, i.e. correcting the code.

Comment: does only_full_group_by has any performance improvement ? why not disable  it ?

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view it would be better address problems and solve them .. ie correct the improper query present in your application .. because these queries improper provide for all columns are not properly included in the group by the unpredictable values .. (essentially random .. . the first who encounters) .. certainly also the size of the application has an important role and therefore the amount of queries to be corrected .. this may result in a proper scheduling of tasks .. and then for a controlled period you can opt for the exchange the sql_mode .. for the checks that I made no appreciable impact on performance

Comment: so whats the point of only_full_group_by ? does it help in any way ?

Comment: @OSAMABINBUSH read this.. https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/… sql_mode=only_full_group_by.ENFORCES you to use GROUP BY correctly... Many people on MySQL are using GROUP BY very very very very wrong..